# Changing forum content tags in string column

Tags: mysql, sql

In the process on migarting from one forum software to another I have been left with mis-matched embedded BBCodes in hundreds of posts.

For example this is the content of one post:

```
Luke Kelly - Raglan Road + Lyrics
[video]https://youtu.be/8xvkvFviIj8[/video]
```

My new forum expects:

```
Luke Kelly - Raglan Road + Lyrics
[MEDIA]https://youtu.be/8xvkvFviIj8[/MEDIA]
```

It's beyond my SQL abilities to substitute the tags.

The table name is `xf_post` and the field name is `message`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Nothing. I'm dumb enough not to know how to do it but clever enough to know how dumb I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple UPDATE command with nested [`replace(string, string, string)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) would work:

```
UPDATE xf_post
SET 
  message = replace(replace(message, '[video]', '[MEDIA]'),'[/video]','[/MEDIA]'));
```